# Is an empty conjunction in propositional logic true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider an illustratory formula
$\psi \equiv \bigwedge_{i \in \emptyset} false$, does $\psi$ valuate to $true$?

Is such a formula ill-formed?

If not, is there a symbol for an empty formula?

The reason why I ask is that I have a definition where I can have a conjunction over a set of constraints, and it would be really helpful if I could interpret an empty set of constraints as true.

Comment: Usually, in a field of sets representation of a boolean algebra, the empty set is interpreted as false.

Comment: @mrp I think, you are confusing subsets and elements of the algebra.

Comment: @StefanPerko Subsets *are* elements of the boolean algebra in the Stone representation.

Comment: The algebra comment made me realize that Boolean Algebra is a lattice with $\wedge$ being infimum, and an infimum of an empty set of elements is the maximal element of the lattice, so here 1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @PunyOne maximal element = terminal object, infimum = product. See my answer

Comment: @mrp This still misses the point of the question. We are not assigning a truth value to the empty set but a truth value to the product with elements from the empty set.

Comment: @StefanPerko Hence why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @StefanPerko I am not very familiar with category theory, so I did not see the connection before, but in general the lattice argument makes sense to me.

Comment: Similarly, $\prod_{n \in \varnothing} a_n$ is not an "empty number" but an "empty product".

Comment: @GEdgar I am not sure what are the implications of the statement?

Comment: I am just reiterating that the question is not about an "empty formula" but an "empty conjunction".

Comment: @GEdgar ok, I edited the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It makes a lot of sense anyway. Truth is usually denoted by $\top$. Consider, that $a\wedge \top \equiv \top \wedge a \equiv a$, so $\top$ acts like an identity of $\wedge$. We define empty sums to be $0$, because then certain recursive formulas still work in some "borderline cases". Similarly we should define empty conjunctions to be $\top$.

Another reason, why that makes sense, is the universal property of a product with some index set $I$ known from category theory . If $I$ is empty, then the product turns out to be a terminal object. The terminal object of a category of propositions, where an arrow $a \to b$ exists, if and only if $a \vdash b$, is $\top$. In lattice theory terminal objects are known as "maximal elements" and products as "infima".

Answer (score 7):

With Stefan, I think empty conjunction is equivalent to $\top$ for the following reason within classical propositional logic:

$\Gamma\vDash\Delta\qquad$ iff $\qquad\vDash\bigwedge\Gamma\supset\bigvee\Delta$

Now for the special case $\Delta = \emptyset$,

$\Gamma\vDash\emptyset\qquad$ iff $\qquad\Gamma\vDash\bot\qquad$ iff $\qquad\vDash\bigwedge\Gamma\supset\bot$

and similarly, for the special case $\Gamma = \emptyset$,

$\emptyset\vDash\Delta\qquad$ iff $\qquad\top\vDash\Delta\qquad$ iff $\qquad\vDash\top\supset\bigvee\Delta$

Comment: Can you confirm the meanings of the following symbols: $$\bigwedge\Gamma$$ means the conjunction of the constituents of $\Gamma$. Likewise, $$\bigvee\Delta$$ means the disjunction of the constituents of $\Delta$. What does $\supset$ mean? Is it sort of like imply ($\rightarrow$)? Is $\vDash$ different than $\vdash$? Do they both mean entailment?