# How does one write a sequent calculus sequent with an empty cedent?

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

How does one write $P \land Q$ in sequent calculus? This would require an empty succedent/consequent?

$$P, Q \vdash$$

or

$$P, Q \vdash \bot$$

?

An empty consequent represents the disjunction ($\lor$) of zero items, which I take to be false ($\bot$)? Is this correct?

---

What about, how does one write $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q$? This would require an empty antecedent?

$$\vdash \lnot P, \lnot Q$$

or

$$\bot \vdash \lnot P, \lnot Q$$

?

An empty antecedent represents the conjunction ($\land$) of zero items, which I take to be false ($\bot$). Is this correct?

---

Since $P \land Q \equiv \lnot(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q$) via DeMorgan's Law, it should be possible to convert the sequent of $P \land Q$ into the sequent of $\lnot(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$, and vice-versa.

---

I'm using the following terminology:

- **antecedent** is what's to the left of the turnstile ($\vdash$)
- **consequent/succedent** is what's to the right of turnstile ($\vdash$)
- **cedent** refers to either an antecedent or a consequent
- **sequent** refers to the "antecedent $\vdash$ consequent" as a whole

---

My goal: to prove DeMorgan's Law using sequent calculus.

---

EDITED: I had written de Morgan's law incorrectly. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: $P\land Q\equiv\lnot(\lnot P\lor \lnot Q)$, and, with hypothesis introduction, $P, Q\vdash$ can't occur (i.e., $P\vdash P, Q\vdash Q, P, Q\vdash P\land Q$, and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An empty consequent represents the disjunction (∨) of zero items, which I take to be false (⊥)? Is this correct?

The empty disjunction is indeed false, so the sequent $P,Q \vdash$ has the same intuitive meaning as $P, Q \vdash \bot$ (namely that it is not the case that *both* $P$ *and* $Q$ hold). However, the sequents $P,Q \vdash$ and $P,Q \vdash \bot$ are not the *same sequents*.

Why? First of all, not all variants of sequent calculus permit the use of the constants $\top$ and $\bot$. You can use them only if your sequent calculus actually has rules for these constants (such as $\bot L$, the left rule for $\bot$). Even if your particular sequent calculus supports these constants, the sequents $P,Q \vdash$ and $P,Q \vdash \bot$ are still not the same. The right-hand side of the first sequent is empty, while the right-hand side of the second sequent contains the formula $\bot$. This means that these two sequents support different reasoning rules. If your rules say that you should get the sequent $P,Q \vdash$, then you cannot assume that you have $P, Q \vdash \bot$ instead - and vice versa.

> An empty antecedent represents the conjunction (∧) of zero items, which I take to be false (⊥). Is this correct?

This is not correct at all. The empty conjunction is true, i.e. $\top$
(see [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493742/is-an-empty-conjunction-in-propositional-logic-true) or [this quora post](https://qr.ae/pGm4Ka)). Again, the sequents $\top \vdash P, Q$ and $\vdash P, Q$ have the same intuitive meaning, but different form. If your rules say that you should get the sequent $ \vdash P, Q$, you cannot assume that you have $ \top \vdash P,Q$ instead.

> Since P∧Q≡¬P∨¬Q, via DeMorgan's Law, it should be possible to convert the sequent of  P∧Q into the sequent of ¬P∨¬Q, and vice-versa.

This is very, very wrong. Intuitively, $P \wedge Q$ says that both $P$ and $Q$ hold, while $\neg P \vee \neg Q$ says that at least one of $P$ or $Q$ fails. They are clearly not the same thing, and de Morgan's law certainly does not say that they are the same thing.

As for the "actual" de Morgan's laws, $\vdash (P \wedge Q) \leftrightarrow \neg (\neg P \vee \neg Q)$ and $\vdash (P \vee Q) \leftrightarrow \neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$, you can prove these straightforwardly in the sequent calculus. If you have left and right rules for $\neg, \vee, \wedge, \rightarrow$, then you will never need to use $\bot$ or $\top$ in these derivations.

Once you get to the cut-elimination theorem, you'll be able to use it to convert between derivations of sequents containing $P \wedge Q$ and derivations of sequents containing $\neg (\neg P \vee \neg Q)$. Similarly, you'll be able to convert between proofs of $P \wedge Q \vdash \bot$ and $P \wedge Q \vdash$. Starting from a proof of $P \wedge Q \vdash \bot$, you'll be able to cut against a trivial proof of $\bot \vdash$ to obtain a proof of $P \wedge Q \vdash$. Starting from a proof of $P \wedge Q \vdash$, you'll be able to write a proof of $P \wedge Q \vdash \bot$ by using the weakening rule on the right.

Comment: @thanks for the detailed answer and the correction. re: **",⊢  has the same intuitive meaning as ,⊢⊥ (namely that  and  are both false)"** I take that to mean $(P \land Q) \rightarrow \bot$ which in order to be true, requires $P \land Q$ to be false, i.e. $\lnot(P \and Q) \equiv \lnot Q \lor \lnot P$. So wouldn't it be more like **(namely that at least one of $P$ or $Q$ is false)"**?

Comment: @joseville Thanks for catching that, that was very misleading wording on my part! Indeed, as you wrote, the intuitive meaning is of course "it is not the case that both P and Q are true", rather than "both P and Q are not true". Will fix (now done)

Comment: no problem. Another clarification. re: $$\vdash (P \wedge Q) \leftrightarrow \neg (\neg P \vee \neg Q)$$. I'm newish to using $\vdash$ so just want to confirm that that should be parsed as $$\vdash ((P \wedge Q) \leftrightarrow \neg (\neg P \vee \neg Q))$$, right? i.e. $\vdash$ has the highest precedence? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: thanks again. Is there an online resource you can recommend for learning about the cut-elimination theorem, weakening, etc. I've been using Wikipedia and whatever else I can find, but you might know a few good ones.

Comment: Alas, I don't know any good free online resources. You may find the relevant chapters of the freely available textbook [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html) useful, combined with other resources you find online, but I don't think the book is a suitable introduction in itself.